# How to add 'None' value in Python Flask Dynamic SelectField using Flask-WTF?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a simple project in Flask and I want to add None value in my dropdown list
Here is a piece if code where I have created the form and named it as `MovementForm` in my forms.py file

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    to_location = SelectField('To Location', choices=[])
    from_location = SelectField('From Location', choices=[])
    add_movement = SubmitField('Add Movement')
```

This is the route where I add my movement

```
@app.route('/movements',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add_movements():
    form = MovementForm()
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    return render_template('add_movements.html')
```

and here is the HTML file

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-3">
        Movements
    </h2>
    <form action="/movements" method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.from_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.from_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.to_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.to_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add movement" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried appending 'None' to the choices but it threw an error, how do I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error do you get? Can you Please add it to the question?

Also, if you change this to the FlaskForm flask, will this solve the issue:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    to_location = SelectField('To Location', coerce=int)
    from_location = SelectField('From Location', coerce=int)
    add_movement = SubmitField('Add movement')
```

Basically because you are using a Dynamic Select field you should add 'coerce=int' instead of choices=[]

Also, how are you adding the 'None' Field?
What are you trying to achieve?

---

> > > **EDIT**

I try to add a 'None' Select field like this:

```
@app.route('/movements',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add_movements():
    form = MovementForm()
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for 
    location in Location.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for 
    location in Location.query.all()]

    // Adding the None in the choices select field in Index 0 
    form.to_location.choices.insert(0, (0, 'None'))
    form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, 'None'))

    return render_template('add_movements.html')
```

---

Comment: Thank You so much, this really helped!